# Convert from character to numeric

Tags: r, database, character, panel

I'm trying to convert a column of my dataset from character to numeric.
That's my attempt

```
# Generate 'key' as the combo of 'countrycode' and 'year'
new_data$key = paste(new_data$countrycode, sprintf("%02.0f", new_data$year), sep = "")
```

Here, as per the description above, I created for my panel dataset a new variable, key, as the combination of countrycode (e.g. USA) and year (e.g.2010), and the outcome is USA2010. Thus, the new variable is a character. I'd like to have this variable as numeric and still keep the label as if it was a character. I tried with:

```
# Generate 'key_id'
new_data$key_id = as.numeric(factor(new_data$key))
```

However, key_id is just a sequence of numbers. For instance, the corresponding key_id for USA2010 is 10500 instead of USA2010.

I tried with

```
names(new_data)[names(new_data) == "key"] <- "key_id"
```

but it does not work

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a column with the years but where it's a factor and the labels are the key? So the column is something like c("2010", "2011", ...) and factor labels c("USA2010", "USA2011", ...)?

Comment: The same outcome I get in Stata. With the command encode key, gen(key_id) , I get key_id as numeric and still appears to be a character. I mean, key_id in stata would appear exactly as key (e.g. USA2010) but it would be numeric

Comment: 'encode' creates a new variable named newvar based on the string variable varname, creating, adding to, or just using (as necessary) the value label newvar or, if specified, name

Comment: I think you just want `new_data$key_id = as.factor(new_data$key)`   - Factors in R are encoded as numeric but have associated "levels" which will be the original strings.

Comment: I've done a step forward but it does not work

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen is easiest than it looked. Thanks. If you want to post the answer, I'll vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `new_data$key_id = as.factor(new_data$key)`

Factors in R are encoded as numeric but have associated "levels" which will be the original strings (that's probably an inaccurate description, it's just how I think of them - see [here](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/factors.html) for a more reliable explanation).